# Does a tool exist to monitor multiple Monero miners?

Tags: gpu-mining, miners

I would like to monitor multiple Monero GPU miners. Has a tool already been developed for this, if not I'll happily do so?

Comment: Can you clarify what type of tool you are thinking about? Do you want to track temperature, electricity consumption, hash rate or something else?

Comment: Everything, something like Apache Ganglia or Graphite... Web-monitoring of a node or series of nodes for things like temperature and hash rates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although im not a big fan of this exact web-portal, personally i'd rather see something built with Symfony for example and have a lot more flexibility, but it does fit your intended purpose i think;

https://getminera.com/

You can customize it to monitor/manage and even build/compile multiple monero miners, but it currently only has examples built-in for other currency miners.

Comment: It gives me a starting place, I'll see what I can make.